# How does memory work across Heroku dynos?

Tags: node.js, heroku

Let's say I have a dynamically created array in node, and I am running it on a heroku dyno:

```
var connections = [];
var wm = new WeakMap();

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

    socket.once('disconnect', function() {
        connections.splice(connections.indexOf(socket), 1);
        socket.disconnect();
        console.log("Disconnected: %s sockets remaining.", connections.length);
    });

    socket.on('idAndApi', (data) => {
        wm.set(socket, data);
    });

    connections.push(socket);
    console.log("Connected: %s sockets connected.", connections.length);
});
```

Now, it is possible the `connections` array and the `wm` weakmap could be created across other dynos.

Will heroku be able to span those variables across each dyno? Or do I need to use some other data-structure (such as a database) to hold the information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynos are independent, and node processes should be stateless (this is true in any environment, Heroku or otherwise).

Store state externally in a place that it can be managed and shared to best suit your app. Redis and Postgres are two of the most common systems for node.

Since you're using socket.io, you should be sure to follow their guide for spanning multiple nodes:

http://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/

Comment: I see it offers a mini example:
   `var io = require('socket.io')(3000);`
   `var redis = require('socket.io-redis');`
   `io.adapter(redis({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 }));`
however are there more fleshed out examples, especially focused on heroku?

Comment: There isn't, but there will be soon on blog.heroku.com (we're about to publish a blog post with a demo on using socket.io on Heroku across dynos and with sticky sessions)

Comment: @hunterloftis 7 years late, but any update on that blog post? I have a game that runs on nodejs with heroku and keeps state in-memory, and i'm running into the problem of heroku dynos restarting once a day, which ejects all my players from their games. i'm a little scared to use redis because i'm concerned it will introduce latency to the game, but i'm just reading related materials and saw this comment.